# How do I add statements to images with seperate onClicks in android studio?

Tags: java, android, if-statement, statements

I am trying to make a memory game with four cards. I used onClick on each of the images to get them to flip. Now I want to add if statements involving all cards that will flip the cards back if 2 are different or leave the cards open if 2 are the same. The only problem is I don't know what I can use to add statements that involve all the cards.
- Should just start with public void?
- Do I use an OnClickListener? ect.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView pic1;
    ImageView pic2;
    ImageView pic3;
    ImageView pic4;

    public class Card{
        public int x;
        public int y;
        public Button button;

        public Card(Button button, int x,int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y=y;
            this.button=button;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // get references to the imageView objects
        pic1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgUpperLeft);
        pic2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        pic3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        pic4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);

        // Setting the initial image
        pic1.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_waterfall);
        pic2.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_waterfall);
        pic3.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_waterfall);
        pic4.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_waterfall);

        pic1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        pic2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        pic3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        pic4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    }

    public void showUpperLeftImage(View v){
        pic1.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_smlee);
    }
    public void showUpperRightImage(View v){
        pic2.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_smlee);
    }
    public void showLowerLeftImage(View v){

        pic3.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_smlee);
    }
    public void showLowerRightImage(View v){
        pic4.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_smlee);
    }
```